# Is there a way to have alias addresses in Google Apps Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I want to be able to have email addresses for people @example.com that do not have Google accounts under our domain. I want to be able to forward someone@example.com to someone@their-email-address.com. Is this possible using Google Apps without adding additional users?

If not, is there a way to get around this using another service to route email based on recipient before forwarding to the MX servers for Gmail?

Answer (score 4):

Yes its possible. You can have a dedicated Google Apps account for all aliases. In [admin.google.com](http://admin.google.com) add all the aliases you need to that single account. Then in Gmail filters, configure one filter per alias to forward them to the appropriate external email (you need to verify them, see [Gmail filters help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en)).

It has issues though. When they reply, it will be from the external email and it can also cause confusion if someone shares drive files with the alias. A sharing email will be sent and routed to the external email but the user wont be able to enter drive of course.